# Form Lines from Strike and Dip measurements

Tags: geology, geography, mapping, homework, structural-geology

I am looking to draw form lines on this map based on the strike and dip measurements taken on site. From what I have gathered it is an anticline with a possible second fault to the right hand side. Can anyone confirm this/give some guidance on where the form lines would go?

[image]